# Comment reputation alert

Tags: discussion, bug

Recently, I stumbled upon a protected question on Stack Overflow. The protection message said I needed at least 10 reputation to comment, so...

> Sure! I have 10 reputation! I can comment!

But, of course, that wasn't the case. As of this writing, I have under 50 reputation. According to the site:

> You need at least 50 reputation to comment.

I don't understand this. What's going on here, and why is there a discrepancy between the two values?

Comment: No, the message says, "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count)."

Comment: Voting to reopen because the duplicate target is less than useful. If there was a canonical that actually explained question protection fully then sure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The protection message said I needed at least 10 reputation to comment

This is false. The message would have said that **to answer** the question, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on the site excluding association bonus.

Answers are free. There are no reputation limitations on answers, except for protected questions which require a minimum of 10 reputation to answer. Comments are not free. You need at minimum of 50 reputation to comment anywhere on Stack Overflow Q&A, except your own posts and answers to your questions.